# How to calculate the integral $\int \frac{\exp{iq\cdot r}}{|\overrightarrow{r}|}d^3r$.

Tags: calculus

How to calculate the integral
$\int \frac{exp(i\overrightarrow{q}\cdot\overrightarrow{r})}{|\overrightarrow{r}|}d^3r$.

I try to calculate it in the polar coordinates. But get the $\frac{4\pi}{q^2}\cos{|q||r|}$, but the right result is $\frac{4\pi}{q^2}$.

Comment: You should know that you should show us what you did. Then it's much easier to answer your question (and people are much more inclined to do so)

Comment: How can the answer depend on $r$?